# Calling an API to modify an App's GUI from non-Main thread in Frida

Tags: javascript, frida

I'm just starting using Frida and have been through fundamental tutorials for code injection and hooking using JavaScript and the python bindings. My current problem is in determining how to call a GUI update method from the non-Main thread. Appreciate it's not possible to do and searching I have found code *in java* that would schedule a task on the Main thread. What I don't know is how to represent this code in JavaScript i.e. how do you represent the following java code in Frida JavaScript (in the injection code):

```
   android_View.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
   {
      @Override
      public void run() 
      {
          android_View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: First step would be decompile the app e.g. in Jadx to get the class name of the anonymous inner class (Runner implementation).

Comment: Hey Robert so I have all that information I think it's more around understanding the syntax to translate to create a new Runnable instance i.e. using something like: Runnable = Java.use("java.lang.Runnable"); this gets you the interface but, how do you actually instantiate in JavaScript given you need to set a up a public run method.

Comment: No the class you see is not `java.lang.Runnable`. The class implements this class, but is an anonymous inner class of the class it is located in. Look at the decompiled code.

Comment: Yeah so finding that is easy enough (MainActivity$1) but, I'm still attempting to execute a GUI changing piece of code form the non-Main thread. Which means (although open to other suggestions) producing a Run method implementation that is fed to runonUiThread call but, it's the nomenclature of doing it in JavaScript that appears challenging. I see what you're saying MainActivity$1 does implement Runnable but I don't see how you go from that stance to getting a non-Main thread to schedule a GUI update on the main one. Appreciate the comment Robert.

Comment: Ok, you want to generate a new Java.lang.Runnable implementatioon containing custom code. See Frida `Java.registerClass(..)` https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#java-registerclass

Comment: You need to be looking at Android Source code for this implementation. If you're not hooking code in the APK itself to change the setVisibility, you need to be using android source code. Find the android class that handles .getActivity() and manually call the runOnUi() method passing it an object thats from the Runnable class. 

This would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the answer following Robert's comment above - thanks that helped a lot.

```
// Assign the javascript code to a variable.
jsCode = """
// Create a method called Cheese that will be exported.
function Cheese()
{
    // Perform the code from injected context.
    Java.perform(function ()
    {
        // Variable to store the view representing the button 
        // to click programmatically.
        var view;
        // Define the Runnable type javascript wrapper.
        var Runnable = Java.use("java.lang.Runnable");

        // Find the MainActivity class in myApp.
        Java.choose("com.example.myApp.MainActivity", 
        {
            // Once it has been found execute the following code.
            onMatch:    function(instance)
                        {
                            // Get the view representing button to click.
                            // 2131436712 id derived from decompiling app.
                            view = instance.findViewById(2131436712);
                            // Define a new class that implements Runnable and provide
                            // the implementation of the run() method which, will 
                            // execute from the Main thread.
                            const MyRunnable = Java.registerClass({
                                                           name:'com.example.MyRunnable',
                                                           implements: [Runnable],
                                                           methods: {
                                                            // run executes button click.            
                                                            run(){
                                                                  instance.onClick(view);
                                                                 },
                                                           }
                                                      });

                            // Create an instance of the class just created.
                            var MyGuiUpdate = MyRunnable .$new();
                            // Schedule the run method in MyGuiUpdate to 
                            // execute on the UI thread.
                            instance.runOnUiThread(MyGuiUpdate );

                        },
            onComplete:function(){}
        });
    });
}
// Export Cheese function to python with name fromage
rpc.exports = {
                   fromage:Cheese
              };
"""
```

Using the above you can call fromage from python and it will issue a click event to the button defined. The call is made from a non-UI thread and scheduled onto the UI thread using runOnUiThread.